# How to optimize recursive function for a graph for clearing and settlement

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, graph

I have to make a module in an Insurance application that deals with clearing and settlement (I think this is the correct financial terminology) between insurance companies enroled in the system. Practically, the system must pair all the amounts that companies have to pay to one another, and only the unpaired (remaining) sums to be paid through the bank. For now there are about 30 companies in the system.
All the readings I did about clearing and settlement pointed me towards graphs and graphs theory (which I have studied in the highschool quite a long time ago).
For a system with 4 companies the graph would look like this:

[image: graph for 4 companies]

where each company represents a node (N1 ... N4) and each weighted edge represents the amount that a company has to pay to the other. In my code, the nodes are int, representing the id's of the companies.

What I did so far... I created the graph (for test I used the Random generator for the amounts) and made a recursive function to calculate all posible cycles in the graph. Then I made another recursive function that takes all non-zero cycles starting with the longest path with maximum common sum to pair.
The algorithm seems valid in terms of final results, but for graphs bigger than 7-8 nodes it takes too long to complete. The problem is in the recursive function that creates the possible cycles in the graph. Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int nodes = 4;
    try
    {
        nodes = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
    }
    catch { }

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    Graph g = new Graph(nodes);

    int step = 0;
    double CompensatedAmount = 0;
    double TotalCompensatedAmount = 0;

    DateTime endGeneration = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Graph generated in: " + (endGeneration - start).TotalSeconds + " seconds.");

    Compensare.RunCompensation(false, g, step, CompensatedAmount, TotalCompensatedAmount, out CompensatedAmount, out TotalCompensatedAmount);

    DateTime endCompensation = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("Graph compensated in: " + (endCompensation - endGeneration).TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
}
```

... and the main class:

```
public static class Compensare
{
    public static void RunCompensation(bool exit, Graph g, int step, double prevCompensatedAmount, double prevTotalCompensatedAmount, out double CompensatedAmount, out double TotalCompensatedAmount)
    {
        step++;
        CompensatedAmount = prevCompensatedAmount;
        TotalCompensatedAmount = prevTotalCompensatedAmount;
        if (!exit)
        {
            List<Cycle> orderedList = g.Cycles.OrderByDescending(x => x.CycleCompensatedAmount).ToList();
            g.ListCycles(orderedList, "OrderedCycles" + step.ToString() + ".txt");
            using (Graph clona = g.Clone())
            {
                int maxCycleIndex = clona.GetMaxCycleByCompensatedAmount();
                double tmpCompensatedAmount = clona.Cycles[maxCycleIndex].CycleMin;
                exit = tmpCompensatedAmount <= 0 ? true : false;
                CompensatedAmount += tmpCompensatedAmount;
                TotalCompensatedAmount += (tmpCompensatedAmount * clona.Cycles[maxCycleIndex].EdgesCount);
                clona.CompensateCycle(maxCycleIndex);
                clona.UpdateCycles();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - edges: {4} - min: {3} - {1} - {2}\r\n", step, CompensatedAmount, TotalCompensatedAmount, tmpCompensatedAmount, clona.Cycles[maxCycleIndex].EdgesCount));
                RunCompensation(exit, clona, step, CompensatedAmount, TotalCompensatedAmount, out CompensatedAmount, out TotalCompensatedAmount);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Edge
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double InitialWeight {get;set;}

    public Edge() { }

    public Edge(int _start, int _end, double _weight)
    {
        this.Start = _start;
        this.End = _end;
        this.Weight = _weight;
        this.InitialWeight = _weight;
    }
}

public class Cycle
{
    public List<Edge> Edges = new List<Edge>();
    public double CycleWeight = 0;
    public double CycleMin = 0;
    public double CycleMax = 0;
    public double CycleAverage = 0;
    public double CycleCompensatedAmount = 0;
    public int EdgesCount = 0;

    public Cycle() { }

    public Cycle(List<Edge> _edges)
    {
        this.Edges = new List<Edge>(_edges);
        UpdateCycle();
    }

    public void UpdateCycle()
    {
        UpdateCycle(this);
    }

    public void UpdateCycle(Cycle c)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double min = c.Edges[0].Weight;
        double max = c.Edges[0].Weight;
        for(int i=0;i<c.Edges.Count;i++)
        {
            sum += c.Edges[i].Weight;
            min = c.Edges[i].Weight < min ? c.Edges[i].Weight : min;
            max = c.Edges[i].Weight > max ? c.Edges[i].Weight : max;
        }
        c.EdgesCount = c.Edges.Count;
        c.CycleWeight = sum;
        c.CycleMin = min;
        c.CycleMax = max;
        c.CycleAverage = sum / c.EdgesCount;
        c.CycleCompensatedAmount = min * c.EdgesCount;
    }
}

public class Graph : IDisposable
{
    public List<int> Nodes = new List<int>();
    public List<Edge> Edges = new List<Edge>();
    public List<Cycle> Cycles = new List<Cycle>();
    public int NodesCount { get; set; }

    public Graph() { }

    public Graph(int _nodes)
    {
        this.NodesCount = _nodes;

        GenerateNodes();

        GenerateEdges();

        GenerateCycles();
    }

    private int FindNode(string _node)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Nodes[i].ToString() == _node)
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int FindEdge(string[] _edge)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Edges.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Edges[i].Start.ToString() == _edge[0] && this.Edges[i].End.ToString() == _edge[1] && Convert.ToDouble(this.Edges[i].Weight) == Convert.ToDouble(_edge[2]))
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Graph Clone()
    {
        Graph clona = new Graph();
        clona.Nodes = new List<int>(this.Nodes);
        clona.Edges = new List<Edge>(this.Edges);
        clona.Cycles = new List<Cycle>(this.Cycles);
        clona.NodesCount = this.NodesCount;
        return clona;
    }

    public void CompensateCycle(int cycleIndex)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Cycles[cycleIndex].Edges.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Cycles[cycleIndex].Edges[i].Weight -= this.Cycles[cycleIndex].CycleMin;
        }
    }

    public int GetMaxCycleByCompensatedAmount()
    {
        int toReturn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Cycles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Cycles[i].CycleCompensatedAmount > this.Cycles[toReturn].CycleCompensatedAmount)
            {
                toReturn = i;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public void GenerateNodes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.NodesCount; i++)
        {
            this.Nodes.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    public void GenerateEdges()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.Nodes.Count; j++)
            {
                if(this.Nodes[i] != this.Nodes[j])
                {
                    int _weight = r.Next(0, 500);
                    Edge e = new Edge(this.Nodes[i], this.Nodes[j], _weight);
                    this.Edges.Add(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void GenerateCycles()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Edges.Count; i++)
        {
            FindCycles(new Cycle(new List<Edge>() { this.Edges[i] }));
        }
        this.UpdateCycles();
    }

    public void UpdateCycles()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Cycles.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Cycles[i].UpdateCycle();
        }
    }

    private void FindCycles(Cycle path)
    {
        List<Edge> nextPossibleEdges = GetNextEdges(path.Edges[path.Edges.Count - 1].End);
        for (int i = 0; i < nextPossibleEdges.Count; i++)
        {
            if (path.Edges.IndexOf(nextPossibleEdges[i]) < 0) // the edge shouldn't be already in the path
            {
                Cycle temporaryPath = new Cycle(path.Edges);
                temporaryPath.Edges.Add(nextPossibleEdges[i]);

                if (nextPossibleEdges[i].End == temporaryPath.Edges[0].Start) // end of path - valid cycle
                {
                    if (!CycleExists(temporaryPath))
                    {
                        this.Cycles.Add(temporaryPath);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FindCycles(temporaryPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CycleExists(Cycle cycle)
    {
        bool toReturn = false;
        if (this.Cycles.IndexOf(cycle) > -1) { toReturn = true; }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Cycles.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.Cycles[i].Edges.Count == cycle.Edges.Count && !CompareEdges(this.Cycles[i].Edges[0], cycle.Edges[0]))
                {
                    bool cycleExists = true;
                    for (int j = 0; j < cycle.Edges.Count; j++)
                    {
                        bool edgeExists = false; // if there is an edge not in the path, then the searched cycle is diferent from the current cycle and we can pas to the next iteration
                        for (int k = 0; k < this.Cycles[i].Edges.Count; k++)
                        {
                            if (CompareEdges(cycle.Edges[j], this.Cycles[i].Edges[k]))
                            {
                                edgeExists = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!edgeExists)
                        {
                            cycleExists = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cycleExists) // if we found an cycle with all edges equal to the searched cycle, then the cycle is not valid
                    {
                        toReturn = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private bool CompareEdges(Edge e1, Edge e2)
    {
        return (e1.Start == e2.Start && e1.End == e2.End && e1.Weight == e2.Weight);
    }

    private List<Edge> GetNextEdges(int endNode)
    {
        List<Edge> tmp = new List<Edge>();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.Edges.Count; i++)
        {
            if(endNode == this.Edges[i].Start)
            {
                tmp.Add(this.Edges[i]);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                this.Nodes = null;
                this.Edges = null;
                this.Cycles = null;
                this.NodesCount = 0;
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~Graph() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I've found several articles/answers about graphs, both in Java and C# (including quickgraph), but they mainly focus on directed graphs (without cycles).
I have also read about tail call optimization, for recursion, but I don't know if/how to implement in my case.

I now there is a lot to grasp about this subject, but maybe someone had to deal with something similar and can either help me optimize the code (which as I said seems to do the job in the end), either point me to another direction to rethink the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can massively simplify this.

All money is the same, so (using your example) `N1` doesn't care whether it gets 350 *from `N2`* and pays 150 *to `N2`* and so on - `N1` merely cares that **overall** it ends up `145` down (if I've done the arithmetic correctly). Similarly, each other `N` only cares about its **overall** position. So, summing the inflows and outflows at each node, we get:

```
Company    Net position
N1         -145
N2         -65
N3         +195
N4         +15
```

So with someone to act as a central clearing house - the bank - simply arrange for N1 and N2 to pay the clearing house 145 and 65 respectively, and for N3 and N4 to *receive* 195 and 15 respectively *from* the clearing house. And everyone's happy.

I may have missed some aspect, of course, in which case I'm sure someone will point it out...

Comment: - there is no clearing house; there is only a third organism that facilitates the process, but cannot intervene in any way in it;
- the reamining money should be paid directly by one company to another, so the main goal is to match as much money as possible so that the money to be paid through the bank is minimal;
- there might be the case when one (ore more) companies don't have any money to pay to another company (one edge, in one direction of the graph is 0), but still the optimization can be maid through a longer path in the graph returning to the node of that company